# If statement not working?

Tags: php, sql

I am a beginner when it comes to php.... I have the following:

I am not sure if it is my if statement expressed wrong or just at the wrong place. I want it not to show the records when the companyname == the businessname! Please advise?

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0  && **($row['companyname'] == $user_data['businessname'])** ) 
{            

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   if (($employed =='1')){


    echo '<h4>  ID                  :  '.$row['idnumber'] ;
    echo '<br>  First Name          :  '.$row['firstname'];
    echo '<br>  Last Name           :  '.$row['lastname'];
    echo '<br>  Reference 1         :  '.$row['ref1'];
    echo '<br>  Reference 2         :  '.$row['ref2'];
    echo '<br>  Reference 3         :  '.$row['ref3'];
    echo '<br>  Gender              :  '.$row['gender'];
    echo '<br>  Company             :  '.$row['companyname'];
    echo ' </h4>';


    echo '<br />';
    echo '<h2>Some Additional Options</h2>';
    echo '<br />';
  include 'includes/admenu.php';
    }

}       
}

else
 {
print ("$XX");
}
```

Comment: Wrong place, `$row` is undefined at this point - it is populated in while loop.

Comment: You can make it so the MySQL query only selects the records `WHERE companyname != businessname`; is that an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$row` variable doesn't exist outside your loop, so it's pointless trying to use it in the `if` statement. You need to move it inside the loop, like so:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    if ( ($employed =='1') && ($row['companyname'] == $user_data['businessname']) ) 
    {
        // code ...
    }
}
```

> I want it not to show the records when the companyname == the businessname!Move the statement inside your loop:

I'm not actually sure if you're trying to display when `companyname == the businessname` or `companyname != the businessname`. Either way, change your `if` condition accordingly and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Guys!

Got it sorted

Comment: @user2792990: Glad to have been of help!